# I need to create an html page where few text fields are hidden and on clicking next button they need to be displayed using javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to create an html page where few text fields are hidden and on clicking next button they need to be displayed. can we do it using javascript and jquery?

```
<label for="Name">Enter a site name:</label>
<input type="text" id="Name"></input>
<label for="Scope">scope:</label>
<input type="text" id="Scope"></input>
<input type="next" id="next" value="next" </input> 
<label for="No">no:</label>
<input type="text" id="No"></input>
<label for="No">order no:</label>
<input type="text" id="order No"></input>   
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b"></input>
```

The html page should display the first two fields on clicking next the fields below the next button should be displayed. can it be done using java script??
plz do help me in coding. how to code it?

Comment: yes. It can be done using javascript. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you tried any code? If so, please post it here

Comment: You must provide what You have tried so far. And read about HTML: type=hidden; CSS: display: block, display: none; JAVASCRIPT: onclick; :).

Comment: `type="next"`? Should be `type="button"`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<label for="Name">Enter a site name:</label>
<input type="text" id="Name">
<label for="Scope">scope:</label>
<input type="text" id="Scope">
<input type="next" id="next" value="next" >
<div id="showdiv" style="display:none;">
<label for="No">no:</label>
<input type="text" id="No"></input>
<label for="No">order no:</label>
<input type="text" id="order No"></input>   
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" data-theme="b"></input> 
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#next").click(function(){
    $('#showdiv').show();
  });
});
</script>
```